# Concatenate two coulmns when the field is NULL

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008

For example I executed the code on SQL like this.

```
Fruits--- Taste
Orange -- good
Apple --  Bad
Apple -- 
Apple --
```

THEN

I go to Crystal Reports

I made a formula field with HTML TEXT format

```
{FRUITS}+"<i>"+"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+{TASTE}+"</i>"
```

Crystal Report is only showing

```
Orange   *good*
Apple    *Bad*
```

Where are these two apples go?

I assume since "TASTE" = NULL therefore, Crystal Reports removed the two apples.

How Can I show it like this on the report?

```
Orange   *good*
Apple    *Bad*
Apple
Apple
```

Comment: Why do you need a formula for that in the first place? Simply use to boxes and space them out as you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the value of `{TASTE}` is `NULL`, then the formula "crashes" because `NULL` can't be concatenated with a string.
Therefore the formula-field appears empty on the report.

You can fix this by checking for `NULL`.
Change the formula like following:

```
If IsNull({TASTE}) Then
    {FRUITS}
Else
    {FRUITS}+"<i>"+"&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;"+{TASTE}+"</i>"
```